# Magento: Add custom module block in checkout/cart

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module that shows a block in "/checkout/cart/".

I use this code in default layout "checkout.xml" file:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="mymodule/myblock.phtml"/>
```

How can I edit my module config file to load the phtml block in "/checkout/cart/" without editing the default layout files.

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-override-magento-admin-view-template-files-quick-and-dirty-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local.xml file in your custom theme folder.

In the local.xml file reference the encapsulating block and add your block as a new node.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout>
    <default>
        <reference 
    name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="mymodule/myblock.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: The question asks about placing a block using a module, not overriding the theme or something else.